# Area of a $r$-tubular neighborhood of a union of convex sets

Tags: convex-geometry, metric-geometry

Consider $P_i$ which is a *regular* $i$-gon in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and whose *diameter* is $1$.

Define a compact set $X$ to be a union of convex hulls of copies of
$P_i,\ i\geq 3$, which is in some rectangle $[0,100]^2\subset
\mathbb{R}^2$.

i) Prove that there is $D$ s.t.

> ${\rm length}\ \partial X <D$

where $D$ is independent of $X$

ii) Then prove that $X$ has $\epsilon =\epsilon (X)>0$ s.t. any $0<r<\epsilon$ implies
that $r$-tubular neighborhood $U_r(X)$ has

> $$ {\rm  area}\ U_r(X) \leq {\rm area}\ X + Cr$$

Here $C$ is *independent* of $X$.

Comment: First problem is soled in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/387384/length-of-a-boundary-of-union-of-unit-balls-in-mathbbr2

Comment: Second is solved in https://mathoverflow.net/questions/387393/area-of-tubular-neighborhood-of-union-of-convex-sets-having-diameter-1-with-ve/387434#387434